# Random number and Microsoft CNG

Tags: random, cryptography, cng

I need to use the Microsoft CNG API to generate secure random numbers for cryptography.

Am I supposed to generate all the numbers using this API, or just obtain a seed value for another random generator from it?

Any help appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many random numbers do you want?  There is only a limited amount of entropy in the MS CNG entropy pool.  For just a single number/key then it is fine.  For multiple keys, then you are better off using the CNG to seed a separate crypto quality PRNG.

There is a description of the MS CNG in section 7.1.3 of [RFC 4086](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4086.txt)

Comment: The Microsoft [`CryptGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) function recommended in the linked RFC is deprecated. Users should instead be using [`BCryptGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom?redirectedfrom=MSDN).